# change selection from ComboBoxColumn in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, selectedindex

I have a dataGridView with different columns. One of them is a ComboBoxColumn with default selections (English, German, Chinese...). I add new Rows programmatically to my datagridview.

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(sn, givenName, mail, department, ToDo);
```

the fifth column is my ComboBoxColumn where currently is written "ToDo". 
I would like to say which of my comboBoxItems should be selected. For example like this:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(sn, givenName, mail, department, 1);
```

Now should be German selected in my comboBox. I set the Items at Form1.designer.cs.

Later on I would like to get the values which Item is selected for each Row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to say:

```
// Assuming your combo box column is named 'comboBoxColumn1'
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(sn, givenName, mail, department, comboBoxColumn1.Items[1]);
```

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.items.aspx) for an example of setting the `Items`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
      DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
}
```

now you can access you values from cell variable.

EDIT:
Ofcourse number 0 in Cells[] is not fitting to your example.